# How to find getter method on basis of JSON Value using Jackson

Tags: java, spring, jackson, jackson-databind

I have json similar to this :

```
Groups":[
         {
            "LogicalOperator":"AND",
            "condition":[
               {
                  "column":"name",
                  "Operator":"CONTAINS",
                  "Value":"Shiva"
               },
               {
                  "column":"address",
                  "Operator":"NOT CONTAINS",
                  "Value":"Vijay Nagar"
               },
               {
                  "column":"city",
                  "Operator":"EQUAL",
                  "Value":"Bengaluru"
               },
               {
                  "column":"country",
                  "Operator":"NOT EQUAL",
                  "Value":"India"
               }
            ]
         }
```

How to find getter method based on **column** value.
Example: Below column is having "name", "address", "city" and "country".

If the **column** value is "name" then dynamically I want find getName() method, if the **column** value is "address" then it should be getAddress()...

Below is the pojo:

```
public class CustomerPojo {

    private String name;
    private int age;
    private String address;
    private String city;
    private String country;

    
    public CustomerPojo(String name, String address, String city, String country,int age) {
        super();
        this.name = name;
        this.age=age;
        this.address = address;
        this.city = city;
        this.country = country;
    }
    
    

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(address, age, city, country, name);
    }



    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        CustomerPojo other = (CustomerPojo) obj;
        return Objects.equals(address, other.address) && age == other.age && Objects.equals(city, other.city)
                && Objects.equals(country, other.country) && Objects.equals(name, other.name);
    }



    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    public String getCity() {
        return city;
    }

    public void setCity(String city) {
        this.city = city;
    }

    public String getCountry() {
        return country;
    }

    public void setCountry(String country) {
        this.country = country;
    }
    
    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "CustomerPojo [name=" + name + ", age=" + age + ", address=" + address + ", city=" + city + ", country="
                + country + "]";
    }

}
```

Below is the code which I have tried. But I want to do it dynamically.

```
private List<CustomerPojo> groupOperatorAND(JsonNode condNode, List<CustomerPojo> list) {
        // String jsonNode = condNode
        // System.out.println(jsonNode);
        String column = condNode.findValue("column").asText();
        String operator = condNode.findValue("Operator").asText();
        String value = condNode.findValue("Value").asText();

        switch (operator) {

        case "CONTAINS":
            if (column.equals("name")) {
                containsList = list.stream().filter(li -> li.getName().contains(value)).collect(Collectors.toList());
            } else {
                containsList = list.stream().filter(li -> li.getAddress().contains(value)).collect(Collectors.toList());
            }
            // System.out.println(containsList);
            // objList.add(containsList);

            break;

        case "NOT CONTAINS":
            if (column.equals("name")) {
                notContainsList = containsList.stream().filter(li -> !li.getName().contains(value))
                        .collect(Collectors.toList());
            } else {
                notContainsList = containsList.stream().filter(li -> !li.getAddress().contains(value))
                        .collect(Collectors.toList());
            }
            // System.out.println(notContainsList);
            // objList.add(notContainsList);

            break;

        case "EQUAL":
            if (column.equals("name")) {
                equalList = notContainsList.stream().filter(li -> li.getName().equals(value))
                        .collect(Collectors.toList());
            } else {
                equalList = notContainsList.stream().filter(li -> li.getAddress().equals(value))
                        .collect(Collectors.toList());

            }
            // System.out.println(equalList);
            // objList.add(equalList);
            break;

        case "NOT EQUAL":
            if (column.equals("name")) {
                notEqualList = equalList.stream().filter(li -> !li.getName().equals(value))
                        .collect(Collectors.toList());
            } else {
                notEqualList = equalList.stream().filter(li -> !li.getAddress().equals(value))
                        .collect(Collectors.toList());
            }
            //System.out.println("AND Group Result --> " + notEqualList);
            // objList.add(notEqualList);
            break;

        default:
            System.out.println("No Operator matches");
        }
        return notEqualList;

    }
```

Comment: I think its better if you can state what is you actually try to solve here. If I'm not mistaken, I feel there is a better way to do it.

Comment: @ray Thanks for your comments, I have added the current working code.

Comment: Are you fetch data from db according to this search criteria?

Comment: @ray yes, fetching from dB.

Comment: Have you check `JPA specification`?

Answer (score 1):

If you put this code into a static method or in a constructor so it is only executed once, it will build a map where the key is the "column" name and the value is the associated get method from your CustomerPojo class.

```
final Map<String, Method> getters = Arrays.asList(CustomerPojo.class.getMethods()).stream()
        .filter(mth -> mth.getName().startsWith("get")).filter(mth -> !mth.getName().equals("getClass"))
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                        mth -> mth.getName().substring(3, 4).toLowerCase() + mth.getName().substring(4), mth -> mth));
```

The code streams the array of methods from your CustomerPojo class and filters out all but the "getter" methods.

It then collects the remaining methods into a map where the key is the name of the getter after stripping off "get" and lowercasing the first character.

With this you should be able to:

```
Method mth = getters.get(columnName);
```

Comment: Great, but here I am facing one problem. How can I apply this column name in list. Example : containsList = list.stream().filter(li -> li.getName().contains(value)).collect(Collectors.toList()); Here how can apply mth.getName instead of li.getname() ?

Comment: li.getName().contains(value) would change to getters.contains(value)

Comment: It's not working for me, this what i am trying,  String st =  getters.get(column).getName()+"()";                                                                    
containsList = list.stream().filter(li-> st.contains(value)).collect(Collectors.toList());  Even there is no getters.contains() method.

Comment: My bad. getters.containsKey(value).